# What would you call a collection of experiences?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Imagine you had a box that held individual experiences.

- These experiences do not necessarily have to be your own.
- Others can put their own experiences in the box.
- The experiences are all related by physical location.
- You can only view the experiences when you are physically near the
  box.
- The experiences are viewed as list from newest to oldest
- The experiences are stored as images or videos

I've thought about TimeLine but it's been beaten to death. Maybe LifeCycle? Something catchy and not cliche.

EDIT:
Image a collection of 10sec videos or images that can only be taken at a specific location. You can only view those images/videos when you are at that specific location.

Comment: What exactly do you *mean* by "experiences"? At the simplest level, all living existence is experience. The ones that we remember and recall most are often called *memories*, but even that is a rather vague category. I think you need to specify what it is about your box full of images/videos that makes them a "coherent set", apart from the obvious fact that they are all *visual records/recordings* of some kind.

Comment: @FumbleFingers an experience being a short video or image

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't really help. Apart from the fact that I've no way of knowing how long a "short" video is from your point of view (a few seconds? less than half an hour?), and that by their very nature *images* have no "duration" at all, the length of a recording has nothing to do with *what it's about*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I View (a play on iEverything), iView, iVu (as in deja vu), uVu/uView/YouView, MemoryBox, Recall, etc.

It sounds like a sci-fi concept. Maybe writers at SE can help.

Comment: yes! That is exactly what I'm looking for. Do you have any other examples???

Comment: @random - gosh, I would be imitating, not creating. So many tropes out there. Sorry. :(  Maybe someone else will try some.

Comment: what are you talking about? I don't care if your imitating i just need ideas to work off of.

Answer (score 1):

My WWWWs [Who, What, When, Where]

Comment: Hmmm. You might as well call it "my stuff". Plenty of people do.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. The word is **[esoterica](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/esoterica)**.

> a collection of items of special, rare, or unusual interest, **often pornographic**.

Comment: Eh, that fits, unfortunately the pornographic associations won't let it work.